# jQuery Slider Thumbnail Width

Tags: jquery, slider, width, thumbnails

I just added a jQuery Slider to my site from here: http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2009/11/beautiful-apple-gallery-slideshow/demo.html

I want to change the thumbnail image widths (menuItem in the stylesheet) from 60 px to 240 px, so the thumbnail images take up the entire container width (960 px). I thought this was a simple fix by editing the CSS, but of course it isn't.

What would be the best way to do this? I have never used javascript or jQuery before, but I'm assuming the edits can be made in the script.js sheet. Any ideas? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As i notice there is a `div#menu` which contains all thumbnails so ,  if you were not changing the height of `div#menu` the height of its children which is `li` ( the thumbnail container whose size you want to change ) will not change. So try to change `div#menu` size first than its children .

Answer (score 0):

Is the first li needed?

```
<li class="fbar inact">&nbsp;</li>
```

if not you can remove it and try this

If you are only using those 4 Items, you could do:

```
li {
    width: 25%;
}
```

or something more dynamic with jQuery:

```
$(".menuItem").width((100 / $(".menuItem").length) + "%");
```

But also, you would need to edit your active image since it is 60px.